# finding max value in a c# array

Tags: c#

I am making a program in c# that will take in a list of names and scores from a text document, get the score on its own and then find the highest of the scores. I can separate the name from the score when it is just one but as soon as I try make it an array I do not have any idea what I am doing.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.IO.File.Exists(@"U:\StudentExamMarks.txt");
        string[] text = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"U:\StudentExamMarks.txt");

        int a = 0;
        string[] results = new string[a];

        for(int i=0;i<text.Length ; i++ )       
        {
            int x = text[i].LastIndexOf("\t");
            int y = text[i].Length;
            int z = (y - (x + 1));
            results[a] = text[i].Substring((x+1), (z));
            a++;

            Console.WriteLine("{0}", results);
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far
the list is as follows

> John  Cross   100
>   Christina   Chandler    105
>   Greg    Hamilton    107
>   Pearl   Becker  111
>   Angel   Ford    115
>   Wendell Sparks  118

like I said when I attempted it without an array I can get it to display the 100 from the first result. I also do not know how when I find the largest result how to link it back to the students name.

Comment: I've removed the namespace declaration as it was messing up the indentation, and I've also removed a lot of blank lines. Please make your code as readable as possible when you post it. Next, it's not really clear what the issue is... it sounds like you should probably have a `Student` class, and you should create a new instance of `Student` for each line of text...

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use a class to hold all properties, that improves readability a lot:

```
public class StudentExam
{
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public int Mark { get; set; }
}
```

and following to read all lines and to fill a `List<StudentExam>`:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(@"U:\StudentExamMarks.txt")
    .Where(l => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l));
List<StudentExam> studentsMarks = new List<StudentExam>();
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string[] tokens = line.Split('\t');
    string markToken = tokens.Last().Trim();
    int mark;
    if (tokens.Length > 1 && int.TryParse(markToken, out mark))
    { 
        StudentExam exam = new StudentExam{
            Mark = mark,
            StudentName = String.Join(" ", tokens.Take(tokens.Length - 1)).Trim()
        };
        studentsMarks.Add(exam);
    }
}
```

Now it's easy to get the max-mark:

```
int maxMark = studentsMarks.Max(sm => sm.Mark);  // 118
```

Answer (score 1):

To find the highest score, you can use `Linq` with `Regex` like this

```
var lines = new[] {
    "John Cross 100",
    "Christina Chandler 105",
    "Greg Hamilton 107",
    "Pearl Becker 111"
};

var maxScore = lines.Max(l => int.Parse(Regex.Match(l, @"\b\d+\b").Value));
```

Here, I'm assuming you have read the file correctly into `lines` and all of them has a valid `int` value of the score.

Comment: Does this work for "Thurston Howell 3rd  123" ?  @kips, I agree w/ [Jon Skeet's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34294230/finding-max-value-in-a-c-sharp-array#comment56330201_34294230) - make `Student` objects. I suspect that will fit in better with your overall project.

Comment: @radarbob updated regex to handle those. Creating `Student` class will definitely be cleaner way to code, but still you'll need some logic to parse each line of text to student object. Tim's answer does that though.

Answer (score 0):

If the end of each entry is always a space followed by the student's score, you can use a simple substring:

```
int max = text.Max(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Substring(x.LastIndexOf(' '))));
```

For each entry, create a substring that starts at the last index of ' ' and then convert that to an integer. Then return the max of those values.